# R Script .bat file - Adding Source before executing

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I have an 'R' file which inserts reads data from a database, does some calculations, then re-inserts data back into a table.

Before i execute the script, I run 'Source' as below..

[image: R Source]

I want to use Windows Task Scheduler to auto schedule this script to run. I am following the guide https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/scheduling-r-tasks-via-windows-task-scheduler/ - When creating the .BAT file it should look something like:

```
echo off
CMD BATCH C:\PATHNAME\RSCRIPT.R
```

What should i insert here to make sure it runs the 'Source' first?

In the R code i have

In the code i have:

```
#use a relative path to locate our common utilities file and source it
source("..//R-Utilities//Utilities.R") 

# use check_install_package function from Utilities.R to install and load 
packages
check_install_package("lubridate")
check_install_package("plyr")
check_install_package("dplyr")
check_install_package("dtplyr")
check_install_package("ISOweek")
check_install_package("stringi")
check_install_package("RODBC")

#give us access to the library of functions this script uses
source("CTB_functions.R")
```

But I need to click the source button before running my whole code, or i get an error (As below).

```
> #this automatically sets the working directory to be where this file is
> setwd(getSrcDirectory(function(x) {x}))
Error in setwd(getSrcDirectory(function(x) { : 
cannot change working directory
> 
> #use a relative path to locate our common utilities file and source it
> source("../R-Utilities/Utilities.R") 
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file '../R-Utilities/Utilities.R': No such file or directory
> 
> # use check_install_package function from Utilities.R to install and load         
packages
> check_install_package("lubridate")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("plyr")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("dplyr")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("dtplyr")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("ISOweek")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("stringi")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> check_install_package("RODBC")
Error: could not find function "check_install_package"
> 
> #give us access to the library of functions this script uses
> source("CTB_functions.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file 'CTB_functions.R': No such file or directory
```

Comment: you can add the `source()` command to your script to source a file. Not sure what's exactly in these files so hard to tell exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I have added in some code which may help

Answer (score 1):

Given your script, there should be no need to click the “Source” button first: in fact, it would execute your script twice.

A few things about your scripts:

> ```
> CMD BATCH C:\PATHNAME\RSCRIPT.R
> ```

This is missing `R` in front of `CMD BATCH`. However, You should probably use `Rscript.exe` instead of `R CMD BATCH`. It’s a modern replacement.

> ```
> source("..//R-Utilities//Utilities.R")
> ```

There’s no need for double slashes: single slashes work.

```
source("../R-Utilities/Utilities.R")
```

More fundamentally, using `source` in this manner can quickly become complex and error-prone due to several shortcomings (e.g circular inclusion, relative paths etc). A better way of achieving this is via the ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/)’ package, which provides a vastly improved replacement for the `source` function, which seems to fit your use-case very closely.

In particular, your script will probably not work: `source` won’t find the files `R-Utilities/Utilities.R` and `CTB_functions.R` because it searches these relative to the current working directory, not relative to the *script directory*. Using ‘box’ fixes this.

Comment: I had added the error log i get when running my code without using the source button

Comment: @SwiftBeginner The code that causes the error is a *completely different code* from the one you’ve shown!